# Regular Expression Get Computer Specs from Plain Text

Tags: python, regex, r

I have a dataset that contains plain text, description about computers and they look similar like below:

[image]

I am trying to predict the price based on the text and here is my approach. 
Since I know they are all computers, I will try to use regular expression to parse out the CPU frequency, memory, disk capacity and screen size... etc. So you will have a matrix with a fixed number of columns... and you can run regular algorithms to predict the price (random forest, linear regression...).

However, I got stuck with the regular expression part parsing out the columns:
Say I am trying to parse the frequency from the text, I imagine it will be some number followed by "GHz".

```
>>> re.findall(re.compile('([.\d]+) GHz'), '2.2 GHz 32 GB')
['2.2']
```

which is good, however, it turns out that regular expression is not that good. Here are a few conditions that my regular expression fails:

```
>>> re.findall(re.compile('([.\d]+) GHz'), '2.2 ghz 32 GB')
[]
>>> re.findall(re.compile('([.\d]+) GHz'), '2.2 Ghz 32 GB')
[]
>>> re.findall(re.compile('([.\d]+) GHz'), '2.2GHz 32 GB')
[]
```

***I am not that good with regular expression and I am wondering can anyone tell me how to locate the number that followed by "ghz" or "gigaHerz".. and there might be some white space between the number and the measure unit.***

***PS: I know R and I think might be a very general statistic question of "How to make a prediction based on bag of words".. if anyone can point me to a better approach, that would be gratefully appreciated!***

Comment: How about `(?i)[\d.]+\s*(?:ghz|gigaHerz)`? or `[\d.]+\s*(?i:ghz|gigaHerz)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the regex

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) ?[Gg](?:iga)?[Hh](?:ert)?[Zz]
```

You can find a demonstration and explanation [here](http://regex101.com/r/mE9eD2).

Comment: That's a really nifty site!

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are not a good fit for working with messy data. Something like http://openrefine.org/ fits this task better.

Using quick and dirty heuristics with RegExp can be good though to measure up your data like:

```
re.findall(re.compile('([\.\d]+) ?g[^\W\d]*z', re.IGNORECASE), '2.2 gigahERTz 32 GB')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for the frequency:

```
re.findall(re.compile('([\.\d]+) *[gG][hH][zZ]'), '2.2 GHz 32 GB')
```

Some notes:
The "\." matches an actual period. A '.' itself matches a single character.
The " *" matches 0 or more space characters.
The [gG][hH][zZ] matches any combination of the letters 'g', 'h' and 'z', lower and upper case.

Answer (score 1):

You want a case-insensitive regex. Also, by adding a `?` after the space, it can match the space either zero or one times.

```
>>> re.findall(re.compile('([\.\d]+) ?GHz', re.IGNORECASE), '2.2 ghz 32 GB')
['2.2']
```

To also match "gigahertz":

```
>>> re.findall(re.compile('([\.\d]+) ?G(?:iga)?H(?:ert)?z', re.IGNORECASE), '2.2 gigahERTz 32 GB')
['2.2']
```

Comment: @thefourtheye What does that even mean? I don't think `1.1.1 GHz` would show up in the data set because that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @thefourtheye Well, sure, but regexes are not exactly a typo-proof solution. What if one of the lines in the data read `1,1 GHz`? Or maybe `1.1 GНz` (where that "H" is actually Cyrillic "Н", U+041D)? I quite frankly see no way of getting a robust solution using only regexes. (And even trying to get close will leave you with an unreadable monstrosity that will probably mess up on edge cases anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

try to do:

```
re.findall("[0-9]+).*?[gG][hH][zZ]", "some text")
```